# Domain WHOIS privacy service that can be used with any registrar

Tags: web, privacy

I have several domain names registered with a registrar that only offers WHOIS "redaction" versus full-blown private registration.  Unfortunately, redaction still leaves the state and country fields exposed (note: this may vary between TLDs but it's true for .com and many others).  Many registrars have a private registration service that replaces the registrant address with their own address, however, the registrar I'm using doesn't have this.

I don't want to change registrars but I'm interested in looking at third-party services that could give me a proxy mailing address that I can manually enter into my whois information.

Domains By Proxy used to be a third-party service that could be used with any registrar, however, they're now owned by GoDaddy and only usable with GoDaddy or any other registrars which are affiliated with them.

I've been looking for alternatives but everything I find seems to be linked to a specific registrar and only usable for domains registered with that registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem that state and country remain exposed ?

Personally I would recommend that you make up your own domain privacy scheme.
A P.O. box + virtual number should do. Right ? As long as the contact is reachable you would be within Icann rules as far as gTLDs are concerned.

It's correct that the amount of whois data revealed may depend on a number of factors such as the TLD, where the registrant or the registrar is located (EU/not EU), or whether it is a private individual or a corporation etc). Plus, there may be some opt-out options available in your customer profile.

Comment: Country/state exposure can be a problem for some people in some scenarios.  Probably a bit of an edge case but for example if you're part of a small/obscure fandom, you may be the only participant in your country/state so if you register a domain for a fandom site other participants will be able to figure out it's yours.  PO box in another state can be logistically difficult. I've looked into general-purpose remailer / "virtual post office" services but they all seem very expensive for a scenario where you'll ideally be receiving zero actual mail.